# Texlive gets downgraded from 2016 to 2013 from Sharelatex image

Tags: ubuntu, latex, docker-compose, dockerhub

Currently I'm setting up my system to run a Sharelatex instance on my server (https://hub.docker.com/r/sharelatex/sharelatex/). Once I've started it, I'm 
running:

```
$ tex --version
```

And it clearly says that it's running texlive 2016. Since it provides only a minimum installation of Latex, I'm doing the following:

```
tlmgr install scheme-full
apt-get update
apt-get install -y texlive texlive-lang-german texlive-doc-de texlive-latex-extra texlive-base texlive-full biber
```

And after all, I'm running the tex --version command again- suddenly, it's texlive 2013 (debian). In addition, the KomaScript framework does not seem to work (\RedeclareSectionCommand not understood by compiler texlive). The interesting thing: I've used the same docker-compose file within a previous installation ~7 months ago running exactly the same commands. 
Within this older installation, I am having exactly the same Late Source and I'm not having kinds of trouble.

Does anybody know how to prevent Sharelatex from downgrading or how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of struggling the issue I found out, that only running:

```
tlmgr install scheme-full
```

Is enough. All other command, especially update and install anything from the stuff mentioned above leads to a courruption of the system.